# What is Objective C equivalent for 'long' in Java

Tags: objective-c

Equivalent to 'long' in Java what do we have in Objective C, NSInteger?

Comment: Does anyone know the reverse of this? I have a long in C and would like to use it in Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java, a `long` is always 64 bits. In C and Objective-C, a `long` might be 64 bits, or it might be 32 bits, or (in less common cases) it might be something else entirely; the C standard doesn't specify an exact bit width.

On OS X, an `NSInteger` is 64 bits on 64-bit platforms, and 32 bits on 32-bit platforms. 32-bit Mac platforms are increasingly rare, so you can probably use `NSInteger` and be fine.

However, if you *always* want a 64-bit integer, you'll probably want to use the `int64_t` data type defined in `stdint.h`.

Comment: I think iphone/ios still has 32-bit longs. See http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9334648

Comment: @NordicMainframe yup, iPhone still rockin' 32-bit longs.

Answer (score 3):

A Java long is defined as a signed 64-bit value, neither `long` nor `NSInteger` guarantee this for Objective-C. For example, on 32-bit systems plaforms, NSInteger and long are 32-bit signed values. If your platform comes with C99 headers (for example when your compiler is gcc based), then you should have `stdint.h` which has platform independent definitions for integer types with guaranteed sizes. The 64 bit signed type is named `int64_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
int64_t someVariable; // 64 bit signed integer, like Java's long
```

You didn't ask, but `int32_t` is the analogue to Java's `int` type (a 32-bit integer).